# How to check if a string is 'float' or 'int'

Tags: java, string, integer

I have a string, and I know that it only contains a number.

How can I check if this number is int or float?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There are many ways to solve your problem. For example, you can use `try{}catch(){}`:

**Solution 1**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "5588";

    // Check if int
    try {
        Integer.parseInt(str);
    } catch(NumberFormatException e) {
        // Not int
    }

    // Check if float
    try {
        Float.parseFloat(str);
    } catch(NumberFormatException e) {
        // Not float
    }
}
```

**Solution 2**

Or you can use regex `[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+`:

```
boolean correct = str.matches("[-+]?[0-9]*\\.?[0-9]+");
```

For more details, take a look at *[Matching Floating Point Numbers with a Regular Expression](https://www.regular-expressions.info/floatingpoint.html)*.

Comment: The regex suggested as a solution is not valid. It does not accept negative sign, and it accepts weird strings like `3.` or even just `.`

Comment: @jbx this is correct and this was from a long time when I start learning regex I fix my mistake hope this can help more

Comment: Yes the new one looks good. `\\d` can still work instead of `[0-9]` but maybe in this case the intent is clearer (since it is parsing a number).

Comment: both `Integer.parseInt("1")` and `Float.parseFloat("1")` will not throw exception

Answer (score 1):

In the [Apache Commons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Commons) *NumberUtils* class.

NumberUtils.isCreatable(String) which checks whether a String is a valid Java number or not.

```
    log.info("false {} ", NumberUtils.isCreatable("NA.A"));
    log.info("true {} ", NumberUtils.isCreatable("1223.589889890"));
    log.info("true {} ", NumberUtils.isCreatable("1223"));
    log.info("true {} ", NumberUtils.isCreatable("2.99e+8"));
```

Comment: But this will not inform whether the String is `Int` or `Float` right? It will return `true` irrespective of it, right? This will inform only if its some sort of number. We need a another check to confirm if its Int or Float.

Answer (score -1):

```
public static String getPrimitiveDataTypeForNumberString(String str) {
    try {
        if (str.matches("^[\\p{Nd}]+[Ll]$")) {
            str = str.substring(0, str.length() - 1);
            long l = Long.parseLong(str);
            if (l <= Long.MAX_VALUE) {
                return "Long";
            }
        } else if (str.matches("^[\\p{Nd}]+[.][\\p{Nd}Ee]+[Ff]$")) {
            str = str.substring(0, str.length() - 1);
            float f = Float.parseFloat(str);
            if (f <= Float.MAX_VALUE) {
                return "Float";
            }
        } else if (str.matches("^[\\p{Nd}]+[.][\\p{Nd}Ee]+[Dd]$")) {
            str = str.substring(0, str.length() - 1);
            double d = Double.parseDouble(str);
            if (d <= Double.MAX_VALUE) {
                return "Double";
            }
        } else if (str.matches("^[\\p{Nd}]+$")) {
            double d = Double.parseDouble(str);
            if (d <= Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
                return "Integer";
            } else if (d <= Long.MAX_VALUE) {
                return "Long";
            } else if(d <= Float.MAX_VALUE) {
                return "Float";
            } else if(d <= Double.MAX_VALUE) {
                return "Double";
            }
        } else if (str.matches("^[\\p{Nd}]+[.][\\p{Nd}Ee]+$")) {
            double d = Double.parseDouble(str);
            if (d > Float.MAX_VALUE) {
                return "Double";
            }
            return "Float";
        }
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    }

    return "Unknown";
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).